# Generate res file in C# during execution

Tags: c#, .net, resources, icons, csharpcodeprovider

I'm writing a little tool to create *"iconholder-apps"* (applications with no/small code part - infobox only).

The application should hold multiple icons (win32 res Resource) und should be created from my .net application (with the `CSharpCodeProvider`)

Is it possible to create compiled win32 resources via winapi / .NET 2.0 or is there a documentation for res files out there (so it will be possible to create these files with raw byte outputs)

(Subquestion: how does reshacker "recompile" the resources?)

Or is compiling with `rc.exe` the only option (I do not like to embed rc.exe if possible)

Or is there another option for creating resources with multiple icons in it (which can be used as link/shortcut icons)

Comment: So you write an application that creates applications? You require a kind of compilation process anyway.

Comment: The compilation process with .net (C#) is very easy.
Example: [CSharpCodeProvider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10324/Compiling-code-during-runtime). I need something to create win32 res resources in .net

Comment: It's just an embedded resource ...

Comment: yes I know ^^ but how to create such resources with multiple icons in .net without rc.exe?

Comment: Why not put everything in an xml configuration file (using Base64) and have a single, immutable exe that opens it like a document? I mean, you don't have any logic, so you don't need to compile anything.

Comment: the icon-holders should work with symbolic shortcut-links [(Image)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/create-shortcut-icons-in-windows-8/Images/change-icon-in-windows8.gif). The main app let u choose some icons and some text an a new!!! exe will be created with the icons you've choosen in the Main-App. So i have to compile something or i need a possibility to change icons in a precompiled template application.